# How to coonect Hard disk partion after installing Linux Mint 19.2

Tags: linux-mint, hard-disk

I installed Linux Mint 19.2 ( Cinnamon 64 bit) but I can't use the main partition for file storage. All downloaded files saved to the system partition. I a new in Linux. Can someone help me with how can I use the main partition as storage? Thank you

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide the output of `sudo fdisk -l` in order we see the organisation of your partitions ?

Comment: Without any information how could we help you? Please show the output of `fdisk -l` and `lsblk -o name,type,size,fstype,mountpoint`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you want to identify your disk, run

```
lsblk
```

to get a list of your disks and partitions.

If the one you want to use doesn't have a mount point (file path) next to it then you need to mount it. If it does have one however you can simply save your files at the mount point and stop reading this answer.

After identifying which disk you want note it's name, it should look like `/dev/sd<letter><number>` it is important to have the number here to refer to the partition and not the disk, even if there is only one partition on the disk.

next you want to mount it with

```
sudo mount /dev/<your partition> /<location to mount it in>
```

this will make the disk avaivable at the specified location.

If you want the computer to mount the disk like this on startup then run

```
sudo blkid /dev/<your partition>
```

then note the UUID and TYPE

next edit your /etc/fstab, using nano this would be:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

and add the line

```
UUID=<your noted UUID>    <location to mount it in>        <your noted TYPE>        defaults     0 2
```

then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> followed by <kbd>Y</kbd> to exit and save the changes.

Hope this helps!